How do I set environment variables for artillery scenarios.flowFunction?
I am trying to set artillery scenarios.flowFunction via an environment variable.
Here is my artillery execution cli statement:
"artillery": "export ARRIVAL_RATE=$arrivalRate && export DURATION=$duration && export MAX_USERS=$maxUsers && export LOB=$lob && export FUNCTION=$function && artillery run ./artillery/$lob.yml"

And here is my artillery.yml:
config:
  target: https://url
  phases:
    -   duration: "{{$processEnvironment.DURATION}}"
        arrivalRate: "{{$processEnvironment.ARRIVAL_RATE}}"
        maxVusers: "{{$processEnvironment.MAX_USERS}}"
  engines:
    playwright:
      launchOptions:
        headless: true
      contextOptions:
        storageState: './storage.json'
  processor: '../playwright/{{$processEnvironment.LOB}}.ts'
  variables:
    function: "{{$processEnvironment.FUNCTION}}"
before:
  engine: playwright
  flowFunction: loginUserAndSaveStorage
scenarios:
  - engine: playwright
    flowFunction:  "{{ function }}"

I keep getting undefined for my flowFunction, but not my other env vars.  I have tried explicitly setting FUNCTION on my cli cmd, but still undefined.
I have also tried without the config.variable configuration, and referencing {{$processEnvironment.FUNCTION}} directly in flowFunctions, but same result, undefined.

Note that using $processEnvironment is deprecated, better to use $env instead, as mentioned in https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/test-script.

Also happens when using a variable for the engine property or when using testFunction instead of flowFunction (alias). Seems like variables are not supported for all property values.
